# Инициализация PyAudio приостанавливает воспроизведение музыки

Tags: python, windows-10, pyaudio

При выполнении строки `p = pyaudio.PyAudio()` звук, который воспроизводился на компьютере, на секунду останавливается. Есть ли способ убрать этот прорыв, или это баг модуля?

Comment: А останавливается в начале воспроизведения или когда?

Comment: ну вот играет нормально, но при запуске кода останавливается, не зависимо от того, когда было начато воспроизведение

Comment: Это может связано с прогрузкой музыки. Вы можете приложить свой код?

Comment: @Tehnorobot там помимо импортов ничего нет, думаю смысла нет

Comment: Я думаю, это связанно с прогрузкой музыки, открытием аудиопроигрывателя и т.д. Впринципе, такая задержка довольно короткая по своей сути.

Comment: Я когда им пользовался, даже не замечал этого)

Comment: Да, кстати, есть же много других библиотек, которые работают со звуком. Например, `pyglet`, `pygame.mixer`, `librosa` и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

попробуй:

```
playsound.playsound(file, False)
```

где `file` - путь к файлу, `False` - включаем асинхронность, то есть музыка будет воспроизводиться одновреммено с другим звуком.